# uniqueness for xml both Attribute & Element level values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have one xsd file having with uniqueness on `RequestNo` (attribute level). And now I want to add one more uniqueness for `EmpID` (which is at Element level).

**Note**: `RequestNo` uniqueness is working fine but not working for Element level (`EmpID`).

I tried with below code. but it is not working. Can any one please correct me.

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <xs:element name="ArrayRequests" type="rootNode">
        <xs:unique name="uniqueID">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//*" />
            <xs:field xpath="@RequestNo" />
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="rootNode">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Requests">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Request">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddEmp">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="EmpID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                                <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                                <xs:element name="Sal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xs:element name="Dept" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                                                <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xs:element name="Email" minOccurs="0" xsi:nil="true" type="xs:string" />  
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:unique name="uniqueEmpID">
                                          <xs:selector xpath="EmpID"/>
                                          <xs:field xpath="."/>
                                        </xs:unique>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="RequestNo" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayRequests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Requests>
    <Request RequestNo="Emp001">
        <AddEmp>
                <EmpID>1001</EmpID>
                <FullName>FullName-1</FullName>
                <Sal>1000</Sal>
                <Dept>Dept1</Dept>
                <Address>Address2</Address>
                <Email>testCP@gmail.com</Email>
        </AddEmp>
    </Request>
    <Request RequestNo="Emp002">
        <AddEmp>
                <EmpID>1001</EmpID>
                <FullName>FullName2-1</FullName>
                <Sal>20000</Sal>
                <Dept>Dep1</Dept>
                <Address>Address2</Address>
                <Email>testCP@gmail.com</Email>
        </AddEmp>
    </Request>
</Requests>
</ArrayRequests>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pretty much their, but what you are saying is 'EmpID' must be unique within each 'AddEmp' element, but as you only allow 1 'EmpID' within each 'AddEmp' this is implicitly true.

You need to apply the rule lower down. I assume you are trying to say that 'EmpID' must be unique within the context of 'ArrayRequests', in which case the following code will provide the validation you require.

```
<xs:element name="ArrayRequests" type="rootNode">
    <xs:unique name="uniqueID">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//*" />
        <xs:field xpath="@RequestNo" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueEmpID">
        <xs:selector xpath="./Requests/Request/AddEmp" />
        <xs:field xpath="EmpID" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Note: it would be nice to be able to apply this rule directly to the 'EmpID', but the xpath expressions used in unique constraints can not look back (i.e. ../ is not accessable), so it has to be applied higher up in the tree.